# Sum of arithmetic progression

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

While solving discrete math problem I've got the sequence of positive whole numbers defined like this (I've looked up simplification to arithmetic progression in the answers):
$$
(n-2) + (n-3) + ... = S_{n-2} = (n-1)(n-2)/2
$$

I am feeling silly, but I can't quite get it. Isn't it just the sequence from 0 to n - 2 reversed? Then it's sum should be equal to 
$$
 (0 + (n-2))/2
$$

Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is just the sum from $0$ to $n-2$ reversed, but then the sum is indeed 
$$ \frac{(n-2)(n-1)}{2} $$
Remember
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} $$

Comment: And why am I so forgetful? Thank you! The proof can be found here: http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/runsums/triNbProof.html

Answer (score 1):

More generally it may help to remember the formula for the sum of $n$  consecutive terms of an arithmetic progression: it is the *arithmetic mean* of the *first* and *last* terms, multiplied by the *number of terms*:
$$a_p+\dots+a_n=(n-p+1)\cdot\frac{a_p+a_n}2.$$
It simply asserts the arithmetic mean of the first and last terms is the same as the arithmetic mean of all the consecutive terms.